# What's the preferred way to start a machine in AWS automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to call from my python script an Amazon web service that will start an EC2 instance
What's the web service that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AWS Python SDK (https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/). To install it:

```
pip install boto3
```

To start an EC2 instance:

```
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(REGION)
conn.start_instances(instance_ids=['instance-id-1','instance-id-2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "web service" (other than the AWS API) that does that.  You probably want to check out the EC2 client in [`boto3`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#client), the python AWS SDK.